# Get input value to controller using jquery Ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax, codeigniter, controller

Here is a form

```
<form>
    <input id="amount"  type="text" placeholder="Amount in &euro;"  name="writtenamount"/>
    <button class="btn btn-lg" type="submit" id="btn1" >BTN1</button> 
    <button class="btn btn-lg" type="submit" id="btn2">BTN2</button>
</form>
```

Which has a input field, all I need to do is push the value to a controller using jquery ajax. But I guess its written wrong.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$('#btn1').click(function() { 
   $.ajax({
     url: 'moneyexchange/invest_first_page',
     type: 'POST',
     data: { 
        writtenamount: $("#amount").val()
     },
     success: function (result) {
        alert(result);
     }
  });  

});

</script>
```

and I have a controller here,

```
 public function invest_first_page(){
        $this->load->helper('form');
        $this->load->library('form_validation');
        $this->load->view('header');
        $userProvidedAmount = $this->input->post("writtenamount");
        $data =  array(
        'userProvidedAmount' => $userProvidedAmount
         );
        $this->load->view("firstPage", $data);
        $this->load->view('footer');
}
```

for now I cant send the value from input to the controller, so need help to fix this.

Comment: Why you have two submit buttons?

Comment: There is no value="" in input

Comment: @wolfgang1983 I have two submit buttons for the input value to go to two different controllers, and I thought if I have placeholder it will get the value in that .

Comment: Placeholder values are not posted by submit.

Comment: @DFriend when I used the form_open, the place holder value did get submited

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually everything is fine, just change your old code to this

```
method: 'POST',
data: { writtenamount: $("#amount").data('value')},
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to check that `$userProvidedAmount` has a useable value.

```
$userProvidedAmount = $this->input->post("writtenamount");
if(!empty($userProvidedAmount))
{
   $data['provided_amount'] = $userProvidedAmount;
   $this->load->view("firstPage", $data);
   $this->load->view('footer');
}
else
{
   //load (or reload) the form with a prompt about the amount being required
}
```

You really need to learn how to use [form validation](http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/form_validation.html).

In the 'firstpage' view access the data like this.

```
<div>You entered <?= $provided_amount; ?>. Thanks for your support!</div>
```

Comment: Hello, I tried it your way, but the problem is that, it doesn't even go to the controller, from the first page with the form, so I guess there is something wrong with the form and the script.

Comment: And I really want to up vote your answer, but since I have only a reputation of 12, I cannot do it sorry.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure, but it looks to me like you have two things going on when you hit the submit button.

1) you are invoking the jQuery ajax method that will send an ajax request and alert the response.
2) the form is submitting in the normal (non-ajax) fashion.  This is because you are not stopping the default behavior of the submit button, so the page reloads.

So, you can either add a preventDefault(); to your jQuery click handler method (make sure to add the event argument to this handler) :

```
$('#btn1').click(function( event ) { 
   $.ajax({
     url: 'moneyexchange/invest_first_page',
     type: 'POST',
     data: { 
        writtenamount: $("#amount").val()
     },
     success: function (result) {
        alert(result);
     }
  });  


  // stop default behavior of form submission
  event.preventDefault();

});
```

Or, since these are not really submit buttons in the sense that you want to submit the form using non-ajax method, you can change the input type of your buttons to 'button'  instead of 'submit' :

```
<form>
    <input id="amount"  type="text" placeholder="Amount in &euro;"  name="writtenamount"/>
    <button class="btn btn-lg" type="button" id="btn1" >BTN1</button> 
    <button class="btn btn-lg" type="button" id="btn2">BTN2</button>
</form>
```

I think either of those methods work.  I would be tempted to change the inputs because having the type of 'submit' is misleading here - you don't really want to submit when these are selected.

I hope that I understood your question correctly, and that I made some sense.